# Python: Appending two lists to list and convert to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have two lists `list1` and `list2`. I'm trying to append these two lists into a `final_list`.
Then convert it to a dataframe.

list1

```
list1 =[['a', 'e'], ['b', 'f'], ['c', 'g'], ['d', 'h']]
```

list2

```
list2 = [['1', '5'], ['2', '6'], ['3', '7'], ['4', '8']]
```

Sample Output:

Appended `final_list`

```
final_list = [['a', 'e'], ['b', 'f'], ['c', 'g'], ['d', 'h'],['1', '5'], ['2', '6'], ['3', '7'], ['4', '8']]


pd.DataFrame(final_list)


    0   1
0   a   e
1   b   f
2   c   g
3   d   h
4   1   5
5   2   6
6   3   7
7   4   8
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to appened multiple lists to a list.

Comment: Can you add to your question your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing the code fragment in the final block is what you want out, and you had problems getting the lists to merge into one list?
If so you can just add your two lists:

```
list1 =[['a', 'e'], ['b', 'f'], ['c', 'g'], ['d', 'h']]
list2 =[['1', '5'], ['2', '6'], ['3', '7'], ['4', '8']]

final=list1+list2

import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(final)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to create an empty final list and then use `extend` to add the elements of `list_1` and `list_2`

```py
l3 = []
l3.extend(list1)
l3.extend(list2)
```